# specify geographical location of table in pandas read_gbq

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

I am having trouble setting the geographical location in `pandas.read_gbq`.

In `google.cloud.bigquery` I can set the location to `asia-northeast1` the following:

```
query_job = bigquery_client.query(query, location='asia-northeast1')
```

However, I fail to do this in `read_gbq`. The following does not work:

```
dat = pd.read_gbq(query, project_id=id, jobReference={'location':'asia-northeast1'}, dialect='standard')
```

Comment: per @MonicaPC - issue was fixed - https://github.com/pydata/pandas-gbq/issues/177